# 'KeyError' while filling an SQL table with CSV data

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm currently working on a project that's requires wrangling OSM data (Udacity Course), and adding it to an SQLite dataset ready for queries.

I'm currently trying to add a '.csv' file to an exisiting SQL table with the following function:

```
with open('crawley_nodes.csv','r', encoding = 'utf-8') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    to_db = [(i['id'], i['lat'], i['lon'], i['user'], i['uid'], i['version'], i['changeset'], i['timestamp']) for i in dr]
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO nodes(id, lat, lon, user, uid, version, changeset, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", to_db)

conn.commit()
```

However each time I try to execute it get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'id'
```

I'm bewildered as to why i'm getting this error. Perhaps the amount of time i've spent at the screen all day.

Thank you for any direction / help.

Comment: The SQLite db has a schema that matches the set created in the ```to_db =```. Here is the SQLite Sschema: 
```
sqlite> .tables
nodes       nodes_tags  ways        ways_nodes  ways_tags 
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE nodes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    lat REAL,
    lon REAL,
    user TEXT,
    uid INTEGER,
    version INTEGER,
    changeset INTEGER,
    timestamp TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the error was. In fact the '.csv' file i had prepared for the SQL database had a 'b' value next to each value. This is why it couldn't find the keys I had identified.

To fix this I modified my osm to csv functions in order to create the csv's correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is id your index?

```
df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

Comment: It's replicating the schema layout that I have created in the SQL database. I'll add this schema into the question.